# Problems when using Pyinstaller with --debug parameter

Tags: python, debugging, pyinstaller

When I compile my python script into exe using pyinstaller with `-wF` parameter, it it launches but gets a `fatal error` after pushing the first button of GUI. So I am trying to remove `windowed` parameter and use `onedir` instead of `onefile` and also add `--debug` for easier debugging:

```
pyinstaller --onedir --debug all script.py
```

but I get many errors and no exe file in the end:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\emimoca\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\emimoca\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\emimoca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\emimoca\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\emimoca\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\emimoca\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 844, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\emimoca\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 791, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\emimoca\Desktop\alternatyvos alternative\script.spec", line 17, in <module>
    noarchive=True)
  File "c:\users\emimoca\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 243, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\emimoca\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\emimoca\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 597, in assemble
    for name, path, typecode in compile_py_files(new_toc, CONF['workpath']):
  File "c:\users\emimoca\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\misc.py", line 150, in compile_py_files
    with open(obj_fnm, 'rb') as fh:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\emimoca\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\Scripts\\pyinstaller.exe\\__main__.pyo'
```

Is it possible to fix this or is there any other way to debug already compiled version of python script? When I run uncompiled script over interpretator it works without any errors...

Comment: Your command is fine and it seems you have a corrupted environment. Try to remove `C:\\Users\\emimoca\\AppData\\Roaming\\Pyinstaller`. Also, try `pip install -U pyinstaller`.